# Disparity map tutorial SADWindowSize and image can not float

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, opencv, matplotlib, disparity-mapping

I am new to Python and have been following a basic tutorial (https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_depthmap/py_depthmap.html#py-depthmap) for creating a disparity map from two images, but I have had several errors.

I am using Python 2.7, OpenCV 3.3.0, matplotlib 1.3, numpy 1.10.2

This is my code v1:

```
     import numpy as np
     import cv2
     from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

     imgL = cv2.imread("C:\Python27\tsukuba_l.png,0")
     imgR = cv2.imread("C:\Python27\tsukuba_r.png,0")

     stereo = cv2.StereoBM_create(numDisparities=16, blockSize=15)
     disparity = stereo.compute(imgL,imgR)
     plt.imshow(disparity,'gray')
     plt.show()
```

I corrected the stereoBM function from the tutorial to match the latest openCV version `cv2.createStereoBM` to `cv2.StereoBM_create` and got an error. (-211) SADWindowSize must be odd, be within 5..255 and not be larger than image width or height in function on the 2nd to last line (disparity=...). I tried reducing the block size but there was still an error, I have checked the image pathways are correct and both images are the same size.

I then have attempted to use StereoSGBM_create instead, v2 code:

```
     import numpy as np
     import cv2
     from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

     imgL = cv2.imread("C:\Python27\tsukuba_l.png,0")
     imgR = cv2.imread("C:\Python27\tsukuba_r.png,0")

     stereo = cv2.StereoSGBM_create(minDisparity=5, numDisparities=16, blockSize=5)
     disparity = stereo.compute(imgL,imgR)
     plt.imshow(disparity,'gray')
     plt.show()
```

However this returns:

> TypeError: Image data can not convert to float.

Any reason why these errors maybe occurring?

Answer (score 1):

Typo error :

change

```
 imgL = cv2.imread("C:\Python27\tsukuba_l.png,0")
 imgR = cv2.imread("C:\Python27\tsukuba_r.png,0")
```

to

```
 imgL = cv2.imread("C:\Python27\tsukuba_l.png",0)
 imgR = cv2.imread("C:\Python27\tsukuba_r.png",0)
```

or better :

```
 imgL = cv2.imread("C:\Python27\tsukuba_l.png",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
 imgR = cv2.imread("C:\Python27\tsukuba_r.png",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

from [cv2.imread](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html)

> Warning Even if the image path is wrong, it won’t throw any error,

Comment: Please accept the answer if it's ok for you. thanks ;-)

Comment: I've tried both versions of my code with both corrections and it's giving the same errors. Thanks for the note about the wrong path not throwing an error though, at least that's one thing I can write off